# ASP.NET page - how to stop from hitting F5 or back button

Tags: back-button, page-refresh

ASP.NET page - how to stop from hitting F5 or back button?? Please help. JQuery, JS working only on few browsers. Please suggest some server side code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no server side code to prevent the back button or F5 from being pressed.  The JQuery/JS is probably about as good as its going to get.

Comment: The non-code solution is to look at your website and see if there is any other way you can design it to not have F5 break or disrupt your webpage.  

Unfortunately for you web pages in general were designed to allow navigation such as back and refresh, and there isn't a huge amount of control over what the client can see or do.

Answer (score 0):

*You can't do that!* Clients are free to do whatever they want. If they want to send any request n times to your server they can do it. If they want to go back (send a request that they have send previously) they can do it. Just accept it.

Whats your problem about back button/F5?

Comment: I need to stop users' on a webpage from going back or refreshing the page. Just for the business rules..can't let them do that?

Comment: No, but you could check (using a session for instance) if a user has already visited the site and redirect him.